# SharePoint Workflow with email

Tags: workflow, email

I am trying to set up a workflow with two approval stages and email notifications. The approval stages are working fine but the emails are not. What I would like is for emails to be sent when the form has received 1st approval, 2nd approval and if it has been rejected. If someone could help me with this I'd appreciate it. I've included the workflow below with the email recipients removed;

```
Step: Step 1

If Current Item:First Approval equals Approved
    Set Status to Awaiting 2nd Approval
If Current Item:Second Approval equals Rejected
    Set Status to Rejected
    If Current Item:Template ID begins with LO
    and Current Item:Second Approval equals Rejected
        Email
Else if Current Item:Second Approval equals Rejected
and Current Item:Delete equals Yes
    Set Status to Deleted
Else if Current Item:Second Approval equals Approved
    Set Status to Approved and Completed
    If Current Item:Template ID begins with LO
    and Current Item:Second Approval equals Approved
        Email 
Else if Current Item:First Approval equals Rejected
    Set Status to Rejected
    If Current Item:Template ID begins with LO
    and Current Item:First Approval equals Rejected
        Email 
Else
If Current Item:First Approval not equals Approved
and Current Item:First Approval not equals Rejected
    Set Status to Pending
    Set Amend to No
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your logs to see if anything is showing up there.  Is this just in your prod environment or a test\dev environment?

When you email, who is receiving the emails?  Are they members of the site or users attached to the list item.

Is this a SP2010 WF or 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I think your intent is to fully automate, but make it simpler.  At least for the email portion of it.

If Current Item:  Status equals 1st Approval
   Email
Else if Current Item: equals 2nd Approval
   Email
Else if Current Item: equals Rejected
   Email